# Ubuntu 14.04: Can't reach link-local addresses

Tags: networking, network-manager, avahi

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have avahi installed.

I can correctly resolve .local hostnames, but cannot reach the resolved link-local IP addresses. For example:

```
$ ping thebox.local
PING thebox.local (169.254.197.130) 56(84) bytes of data.
[...]
(no answer)
```

If I check the routing tables I see there are no entries for the link-local network:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.100   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Shouldn't the network manager (or avahi) automatically create an entry for 169.254.x.x there?

Comment: Wait... what are you asking? The DNS has nothing to do with your network route configuration. Even if you can resolv an address it will just try using a default gateway, if there is no specific route for that network,  which for you is your eth0 interface. That was automatically added by your NetworkManager. So the answer is, no the NetworkManager will not add a route automatically that is not connected to one of your ethernet ports.

Comment: Yes I know. Sorry if I was not very clear. What I am saying is "avahi is properly installed" (that's why I say I can resolve .local addresses). And then the question is, if avahi is installed, shouldn't it have configured NM to create a route for 169.254.x.x ?

Comment: No it shouldn't, also the IP you're trying to connect to is a self assigned one. Are you sure it even exists somewhere, since your network seems to be 192.168.0.0/24. Edit: Also Avahi is by default installed, it's not if you use an ubuntu server but can be installed by the package `libnss-mdns`

Comment: Yes, I am sure it exists, and in fact if I manually add a routing entry for the link-local network I can ping it.

Comment: *"Shouldn't the network manager automatically create an entry for 169.254.x.x there?"* No, it shouldn't. You may want to assign a supplementary IP address to the network interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further into this, I have found that a route for 169.254.x.x is indeed automatically created (by the `/etc/avahi/avahi-autoipd.action` specifically) but only when DHCP fails and a link-local IP is assigned to the machine. This route is also automatically removed if an IP address is later obtained via DHCP.

I knew that this route was created automatically but I thought it was created always. Now I see it is only created when a link-local IP address is assigned.

**Update:** I wonder why this route isn't created by default. This would make it possible to communicate with devices that only have a link-local address, even if Ubuntu is not using a link-local address itself. This is well described [in this technical article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1357/_index.html).

Comment: That's a good question.  Network-manager does actually create this route but ifupdown (/etc/network/interfaces) does not.In terms of using ifupdown it seems that things are moving to 'netplan' and thus either network-manager or systemd-networkd for 17.10 so adding support for this to ifupdown is unlikely.

Comment: In my case it seems to be the opposite. Network Manager is not doing that for me (or I am missing something), but ifupdown seems to be prepared to handle this, specifically there is a script /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd which creates the necessary routes. But this file does not seem to be used by Network Manager....